# How should dates as strings be filtered using NSPredicates?

Tags: objective-c, json, nspredicate

When my app gets the web service response, the objects are stored in JSON. The data displayed to the user is based on the content filters which they have selected.

Filtering entry types and statuses are not an issue, however dates are not sorting correctly. In the viewcontroller the date is shown as a string to the user, so I never convert it to an NSDate.

Is it possible to do a time comparison with a date as a string using NSPredicates?  If not, what solutions are available to me to enable users to filter entries by date (entries within last 1 day, two days, within the last week)?

Comment: You can use a predicate with blocks, that'd use a NSDateFormatter and a NSDate to compare. Allocating/init the NSDateFormatter only once (not in the block).